# ArrayList String input

Tags: java, arraylist, input

I have a method, which search in an ArrayList what contains objects with two private fields. Here is the method:

```
public int searchContactName(String name){

    int foundIndex =-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        if(contacts.get(i).getName() == name){
            foundIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return foundIndex;
}
```

It's work well if I use it like this:

```
searchContactName("xyName");
```

But if I try to use it with a scenner.next() like thins, for the same name

```
String name = scanner.next();
searchContactName(name);
```

It's give me -1. I don't understand, I need to format some way the input? It is the same type or it is different some way if I use the scanner?

Comment: change `contacts.get(i).getName() == name` to `contacts.get(i).getName().equals(name)`

Comment: Have you tried using `scanner.nextLine()`? You should receive the same input only that nextLine() explicitly returns a String.

Comment: How to compare Strings in Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==` operator checks that two objects are the same instance of the object, which happens to be true for hardcoded string literals. The *correct* way to check this, however, is with the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method, which tests whether two objects have the same value:

```
public int searchContactName(String name){

    int foundIndex =-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        if (contacts.get(i).getName().equals(name)) { // here!
            foundIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return foundIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use String.equals() instead of ==

Your check should be

```
  if(contacts.get(i).getName().equals(name))
```

also see this for reasons why you should not use == [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
String name = scanner.nextline(); searchContactName(name);
```

And:

```
if(contacts.get(i).getName().equalsIgnpreCase ( name)) ...
```

Comment: What problem would changing `next` to `nextLine` solve?

Answer (score 0):

You should use equals method to compare strings values

```
public int searchContactName(String name){

    int foundIndex =-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        if(contacts.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
            foundIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return foundIndex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

scanner.next() Will return Object in ArrayList. In your case its not exactly name. You should call getName() method on object which you got from scanner.next(). Verify code "contacts.get(i).getName()" which you wrote where its working

Comment: "You should call getName() method on object which you got from scanner.next()" doesn't make sense. `Scanner` is always used to scan input representing text, so `next` can only return `String` (which is technically an Object) but String class doesn't have `getName()` method. Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: Agree. My bad. Wrongly interpreted.